# When I make Widget build in flutter, can I make it without Scaffold?

Tags: flutter, webview, scaffold

I'm trying to make an app with just a webview with flutter.

1). When I make Widget build, can I make it without Scaffold like the code below?

2). I want to reduce even one frame.
If I build without scaffold will it help reduce frames?

And 3). I'm only making webviews, can I remove SafeArea as well?

```
return Container(

    child: SafeArea(

         child: WebView(
            ..
         ),
    )
);
```

}

Comment: If I understood your question right, you want to create a webview on Flutter, and you're asking if the Scaffold will affect the performance?

Comment: Yes, that's right. I'm worried about the performance decrease when not using scaffold

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question shortly:

1. The `Scaffold` or a `Material` widget is required if your widget is a Widget (such as `TextField`) that required a `Material` parent widget. No if your widget is not.

   If you omit the `Material` parent widget, an error will happens (See the end of the post for more info).
2. In this case, since your widget is a `WebView` (which I assume is from this package [webview_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter)), you don't need a `Scaffold`.
3. You can simply use it like this:

```dart
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

class WebViewExample extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  WebViewExampleState createState() => WebViewExampleState();
}

class WebViewExampleState extends State<WebViewExample> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WebView(
      initialUrl: 'https://flutter.dev',
    );
  }
}
```

P/s: The error when you omit a `Material` parent will be like:

```
I/flutter ( 5187): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter ( 5187): The following assertion was thrown building InputDecorator(decoration: InputDecoration(hintText:
I/flutter ( 5187): "Type something"); baseStyle: null; isFocused: false; isEmpty: true; dirty):
I/flutter ( 5187): No Material widget found.
I/flutter ( 5187): InputDecorator widgets require a Material widget ancestor.
I/flutter ( 5187): In material design, most widgets are conceptually "printed" on a sheet of material. In Flutter's
I/flutter ( 5187): material library, that material is represented by the Material widget. It is the Material widget
I/flutter ( 5187): that renders ink splashes, for instance. Because of this, many material library widgets require that
I/flutter ( 5187): there be a Material widget in the tree above them.
I/flutter ( 5187): To introduce a Material widget, you can either directly include one, or use a widget that contains
I/flutter ( 5187): Material itself, such as a Card, Dialog, Drawer, or Scaffold.
```

Comment: Of course I use Material .
I want to use it like the code you wrote.
But I'm worried about the performance decrease when not using scaffold

Comment: @아이엠초코 It won't affect the performance. It would probably save some minor time when your app don't have to render the `Scaffold` and go straight to the `WebView`